# Views shrink when using keyboard with PercentageLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

i have 2 different XML files. One is  *signup.xml* the other *chat.xml*, both constructed with the PercentageLayout library.

the *signup.xml* works great - opening keyboard doesnt change any view.
However, in *chat.xml* whenever i pop the keyboard the view shrinks or out of screen, and i dont know why since i constructed them both nearly in the same manner, only i suspect that because i use `ScrollView` this happens.

The problematic layout, `chat.xml` :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- top -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="8%"
    android:background="#075607"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#acddf4"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="jfioewjfoiewjfoi"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Mid -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mid"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="84%"
    android:background="#b1b7b3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bg" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chatWindowContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
<!-- Bottom -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mid"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="8%"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSendMessage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />



</LinearLayout>
```

And the working layout, `signup.xml` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/signup"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mid"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    app:layout_heightPercent="35%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    android:baselineAligned="true">
    <!-- Username -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/person" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUsername_signup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/text">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Email -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/email" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail_signup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="email@address.com"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Password1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/password" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword1_signup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="pass"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Password2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/password" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword2_signup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="pass"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Spinner and RadioGroup-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rgRadius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Kilometer" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mile" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Image -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mid"
    app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    android:baselineAligned="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/faceless" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Button -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/image">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bSignup"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are using softinputmod with activity in manifest.xml?

Comment: I dont use softinputmethod anywhere

Comment: Hey, i'm at the same problem, have you ever found a solution?

Comment: any luck here? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout solve your shrinking layout problem I tested following layout.

Add following entry with activity tag : `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

And Your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- top -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#075607"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#acddf4"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="jfioewjfoiewjfoi"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Mid -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:background="#b1b7b3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chatWindowContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Bottom -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionNone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"


            android:layout_gravity="right" />



    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you but i really wanted a solution with PercentageLayout because the xml makes alot more sense that way.
Also i already have a working 'regular' that works just fine but i wanted to rebuild it with PercentageLayout